# Git not pushing all files and folders

Tags: git, github

[image: In here you can see my Git Bash process]
[image: In here is my GitHub repo on GitHub website]
[image: In here is what my master directory looks like]

I'm trying to push the whole directory onto my repository.
Every time I try to do this, it just pushes the README, nothing else.  As you can see in the second photo, there is only README on there.  In the third picture is what my master directory looks like.  The first picture is the whole process of adding and pushing, showing you that I've done the necessary steps.

What do I need to do to ensure all files and folders get pushed?

Comment: You need to use `git add file_name` to tell git which files you want it to push remotely.

Comment: There's no quicker way?  It'd suck to manually add like 100 files

Comment: You can add whole directories. You can also use wildcard characters - `git add *`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `git add *` to add all files in a directory.

You also need to make sure you run `git commit -m "your commit message"` before you push

Comment: `git commit -am "your commit message"` will save you from having to re-add files you've edited since you added them.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it for me. I had the same exact problem.

Over the .git file in the main file there is a config. Look over the file_mode and ignorecase as i setup.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1- git init

2-
git add `<folder1> <folder2> <etc.>`

**OR** to upload all files and folders use a dot

git add .

**OR** for all html files in a folder use *html

git add *.html

3- commit -m "Your message about the commit"

4- remote add origin https://github.com/yourUsername/yourProjectName

5- push -u origin master

6- Change **main** to **master** on your github account like below screenshot
[image]